# Save Properties File MOST EFFICIENT

Tags: java, properties-file

Which of these ways is better (faster, less storage)?

1. Save thousands of `xyz.properties` in every file — about 30 keys/values
2. One `.properties` file with all the data in it — about 30,000 keys/values

Comment: Maybe a database fits better here?

Comment: If the file is locked during read/write and the application is multi-threaded, you'll run into performance issues.  Surely a database is a better fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are **two** aspects here:

1. As Guenther has correctly pointed out, dealing with files comes with **overhead**. You need "file handles"; and possible other data structures that deal with files; so there might many different levels where having **one** huge file is better than having many small files.
2. But there is also "maintainability". Meaning: from a developers point of view, dealing with a property file that contains 30 K key/values is something you really don't want to get into. If everything is in one file, you have to constantly update (and deploy) that one huge file. One change; and the whole file needs to go out. Will you have mechanisms in place that allow for "run-time" reloading of properties; or would that mean that your application has to shut down? And how often will it happen that you have duplicates in that large file; or worse: you put a value for property A on line 5082, and then somebody doesn't pay attention and **overrides** property A on line 29732. There are many things that can go wrong; just because of having all that stuff in one file; unable to be digested by any human being anymore! And rest assured: debugging something like that will be **hard**.

I just gave you some questions to think about; so you might want to step back to give more requirements from your end.

In any way; you might want to look into a solution where developers deal with the many small property file (you know, like **one** file per functionality). And then you use tooling to **build** that one large file used in the production environment.

Finally: if your application really needs 30K properties; then you should very much more worry about the quality of your product. In my eyes, this isn't a design "smell"; it sounds like a design fetidness. Meaning: no reasonably application should require 30K properties to function on.

Answer (score 1):

Opening and closing 1000s of files is a major overhead with the operating system, so you'd probably best off with one big file.